# ALSA PCM device network streaming

Tags: alsa, pcm, pulseaudio

I am writing an application in C++ intended to stream data from a PCM device (microphone) to a remote server.  I have successfully been able to stream a recorded wav file to the server, and I have been able to output the mic input to a file.  The next step is to merge my 2 programs...open the PCM device, and then stream what gets put into the buffer to the server.

I have read that I will need to use Pulse Audio to do this because ALSA does not have a server.  Is this accurate? Does anyone have any examples or resources? I have had minimal luck trying to research this online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you need *another* server? Just remove all the file handling.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you!  That got me thinking down a different path and was able to just send the buffer using socket programming.